# How can I serve a tree of html for a domain under a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app running example.com

I have a very simple and completely independent site, example-1.com. I have a tree of static html/css for it.

What's the most simple way to serve this domain out of /public ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're wanting to serve static pages from within your rails app?

There's several ways to do this, but one of the easiest is to use the [high_voltage gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage), which makes managing static pages and their routing easy, but it's not really that hard to do on your own either.

The main advantage to not serving them directly from /public is that your views can use the layouts already defined for your site.

If you're wanting to maintain the pages in a CMS, check out [comfy-mexican-sofa](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa), which is a CMS, but can be easily integrated into an existing app to take care of static pages.

Comment: what isn't directly supported by either of those solutions is the domain name situation i described in my question

Comment: Well, if you are wanting to have two different domains (for example, example-1.com and example.com), the only way I know how to do that would be to use either namespacing on the routes(example.com/pages/*) or subdomains(*.example.com), then at your domain name registrar, setup redirection to the namespaced routes accordingly. I didn't understand that from your question before. I'll make this an answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do t with `iframe` html tag. I had the same issue.
You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608656/how-to-serve-static-html-pages-with-rails)