# How to serve static html pages with Rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Rails application with documentation which is static html pages in the /public folder.

The tree of my public folder:

```
-public
  -docs
    -intro
      introduction.html
    -css
      some.css
    index.html
```

Index.html file is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/some.css" type="text/css" />
Some of the text
<li>href="intro/introduction.html"><em>Introduction</em></a></li>
```

When I open index page css isn't loaded, and when I try to click on link it says routing error. As I understood static pages don't know where to look for css and other html pages.

I just want static pages without any routes and controllers, nginx.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not overkill if he has a full-featured Rails app and just wants to serve static content on the side.

Comment: @Jesper Correct, i've got full-featured Rails app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the public folder content is accessible via "/"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/docs/css/some.css" type="text/css" />
```

You can use [high_voltage gem](http://geekmonkey.org/articles/9-static-pages-with-high-voltage) to generate static_pages

Answer (score 1):

Its perfectly valid to serve static files (pages or not) via the public directory. As Kirka121 said rails is not really built for this purpose but can still work with it.

In development environment it should just work to serve whatever files you have in public, for production environment you might need to configure whatever server you use to serve them - but this should be covered by its normal setup anyway, if not its set up wrong.

So by default the rails public folder can directly by accessed at the root of the project.

As far as your code goes the relative links/urls seem to be the issue. Its generally better to use absolute paths for everything not to confuse anything, which leads to very hard to find bugs.

With your folder structure and example this would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/docs/css/some.css" type="text/css" />
Some of the text
<li><a href="/docs/intro/introduction.html"><em>Introduction</em></a></li>
```